# Rundeck: some jobs stuck on running state via SSH

Tags: ssh, rundeck

Some jobs stuck on running state from time to time , so we have to kill such executions. What's a problem can be? Is there a way to fix it?

Rundeck 3.3.0 and 4.0.1
Node executor: SSH
Node: Windows 2012R2, openssh 8.1p1 and 8.9p1

This problem is absent via WinRM. We chose ssh cause we can kill jobs with processes on windows node. WinRM can't do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide more information about your node definition. Also, try another SSH node executor like SSHJ.

Answer (score 0):

we encounter the same problem here with PPA 4.16.0.

The problem only seems to occur when running PowerShell Commands on Windows 7 systems via OpenSSH (e.g. powershell.exe "Get-Date -format r"). Windows 10 is working well. It makes no difference whether using a command or a script for the job workflow.

Here's my node definition:

```
<HOSTNAME>:
  hostname: "<fqdn>"
  username: "ADMIN"
  tags: "XYZ"
  environment: "production"
  osFamily: "Windows"
  ssh-authentication: "password"
  ssh-password-storage-path: "path/to/credentials"
```

Comment: Interestingly, while still on running state, a valid and complete Log Output is visible for the stucking nodes.